# Can I marry Aela the huntress after completing the quest: Liberate Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have wanted to marry Aela but now I have completed the quest 'Liberate Skyrim' (the quest where the Stormcloaks take over Whiterun).

Now I can't find her - is it possible to marry Aela after completing 'Liberate Skyrim'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer to this is *Probably Not*

Aela has a strong loyalty to Jorrvaskr. Which has its loyalty to the Imperials. If the Imperials win then Vignar Gray-Mane is the new Jarl of Whiterun.

She is part of many factions but these are of importance :

1. GuardFaction (makes an actor a guard)
2. PotentialMarriageFaction
3. TownWhiterunFaction

She is part of Town Whiterun faction and Guard faction. Which automatically makes her not available for marriage in your case, since entire of Whiterun will not have Whiterun guards. They are replaced by Stormcloak soldiers.

Also according to her entry at [UESP](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Aela_the_Huntress):

Aela is part of the *Guard Faction*. There is a bug wherein due to being part of the Guard faction, Aela may behave erratically if she's following you when beginning the Battle For Whiterun quest.

According to entry for [Battle For Whiterun](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Battle_for_Whiterun_%28Stormcloaks%29) at UESP Stormcloak version:

Also during Battle For Whiterun (Stormcloak version), Aela the Huntress may disappear if she is your wife at the time. She may come back eventually after you moved on to the next Quest, Liberation of Skyrim.

Since you have completed `Liberation of Skyrim` quest and still can not find Aela, you probably might not be able to marry her.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know I could marry her after I did that quest.  If you can't find her, maybe she died somehow?  I don't really know.  All I know is I finished that quest and sometime later I decided to marry her.